# Using GRDBCombine to obtain unique items and display them in a list with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, grdb, grdbcombine

I have a sample test project at https://github.com/EricG-Personal/grdb_test.git

In ContentView.swift, I currently have one list that shows all of the items in the Database.

Below that, I would like another list that shows all of the unique 'names' from the test table.

I am getting lost in the details between GRBD, Combine, and SwiftUI and am not sure what the code would look like to provide the second list with the data it needs from the database while using GRDBCombine.